# SQL Server does not rollback trigger transaction to savepoint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, transactions

I am facing an issue trying to set up a transaction within a trigger of my view. Here is my DDL setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entity1 (
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    attr1 INT NOT NULL,
    attr2 INT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE TABLE entity2 (
    entity1_id INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES entity1(id),
    attr3 INT NOT NULL,
    attr4 INT NOT NULL
);
GO

CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4
FROM entity1 AS e1 
INNER JOIN entity2 AS e2 
ON e1.id = e2.entity1_id;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER tg_my_view_ins ON my_view
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SAVE TRANSACTION here; -- checkpoint
        INSERT INTO entity1 (attr1, attr2) 
        SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM inserted;
        INSERT INTO entity2 (entity1_id, attr3, attr4) 
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), attr3, attr4 FROM inserted;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION here; -- rollback to checkpoint in case on an error
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

As you can see, I make a savepoint while in the trigger, and rollback in case of any errors (I assume that constraint errors are also handled by TRY/CATCH blocks).
The problem is, when I execute bad inserts within the transaction, trigger error handling block does not rollback:

```sql
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        -- successful insert
        INSERT INTO my_view (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) VALUES (1,2,3,4);
        SELECT * FROM entity1; -- one entity

        -- i wrap the bad insert into try/catch so the error is discarded, 
        -- but still rolled back
        BEGIN TRY
            INSERT INTO my_view (attr1, attr2, attr3) VALUES (3,2,1);
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        END CATCH;

        SELECT * FROM entity1; -- should only have one entity, but has two
    ROLLBACK; -- discard the whole transaction
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK; -- discard the whole transaction in case of any errors
END CATCH;
```

[image: result output]

I do not seem to be able to set up the trigger the way it would not create orphan records in case of an error. I have tried using `BEGIN TRANSACTION here` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION here` within my trigger instead of `SAVE TRANSACTION here` as well, with no luck. What is the correct way to handle constraint erros within triggers?

The execution setup I would like to keep the way it is, if possible. I create and rollback the transaction for testing purposes. I wrap the bad insert into a try/catch block to discard the error I know should happen.

Comment: Aside: Your use of `Scope_Identity` makes it appear that your trigger won't cope gracefully when `inserted` contains more than one row.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @HABO! I guess I should use `OUTPUT` clause to store the IDs of all newly inserted rows.

Comment: I would revise any design that uses savepoints. Far too complicated to maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seemingly confused behaviour can be made clear by adding error logging into your `catch` blocks. The following modification of your test code adds error logging (and some other improvements), which shows what actually happens in the process:

```
begin try
  begin transaction;

  INSERT INTO dbo.my_view (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) VALUES (1,2,3,4);
  SELECT * FROM dbo.entity1;

  BEGIN TRY
  INSERT INTO dbo.my_view (attr1, attr2, attr3) VALUES (3,2,1);
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  -- Logging - inner CATCH
  select 'Inner', @@trancount, error_number(), error_message(), error_procedure(), error_line();
  END CATCH;

  select * from dbo.entity1;
  rollback;

end try
begin catch

  -- Logging - outer CATCH
  select 'Outer', @@trancount, error_number(), error_message(), error_procedure(), error_line();

  -- Conditional rollback, because some errors always terminate the transaction
  if @@trancount > 0
    rollback;

end catch;
```

If you run this code with your trigger intact, you will see an error caught by the inner `CATCH`:

> 3931
>
> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot be rolled
>   back to a savepoint. Roll back the entire transaction.

Searching by the error number leads to [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/137305/48699) with a similar question. In his answer, Rutzky shows that the culprit of this behaviour is the `XACT_ABORT` session option which is apparently set to `ON` for triggers by default. If your intent is to pursue your trigger-based architecture, then turning this option off inside your trigger will help:

```
create or alter trigger dbo.tg_my_view_ins
on dbo.my_view
instead of insert as

-- Implicitly set to ON in triggers by default; makes error handling impossible
set xact_abort off;

begin try
  save transaction here;

  INSERT INTO dbo.entity1 (attr1, attr2) 
  SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM inserted;

  INSERT INTO dbo.entity2 (entity1_id, attr3, attr4) 
  SELECT e.id, attr3, attr4
  FROM inserted i
    -- The actual JOIN condidions should reference a natural key in the master table.
    -- This is just an example.
    inner join dbo.entity1 e on e.attr1 = i.attr1 and e.attr2 = i.attr2;

end try
begin catch

  if @@trancount > 0
    rollback transaction here;

end catch;
return;
GO
```

(Again, I have corrected several other issues with your code.)

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I did not realize that `XACT_ABORT` is switched to `ON` implicitly in triggers. Also, thanks for pointing out and correcting the issues in my setup.